# No puedo usar dos validaciones de usuario o guards en laravel

Tags: laravel, auth, middleware, guards

No puedo usar o agregar una segunda autenticación en laravel mediante los guards

Tengo mi funcion donde valido los datos despues del formulario:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    //Valida que sean enviados data en el request de correo y contraseña en los inputs del login
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);


    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, $remember = true))
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);

    }
       
    if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt($credentials, $remember = true)) 
    {   
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);    
    }

    return back()->with('message', 'Credenciales Incorrectas');
```

}

Por defecto el Guard "Web" si funciona y me deja acceder a la vista de destino por que encuentra al usuario, pero si este usuario no esta dentro del modelo users va hacia la siguiente validacion que es el guard "student" el cual tengo ya mi modelo definido y aun que tengo mi variable $remember = true esta no guarda la autenticación y por ende me tira null en la siguiente vista.

en mi Auth.php tengo;

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
        'remember' => true,
        'expire' => 1440, // Duración en minutos (ejemplo: 1 día)
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Students::class,
    ],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'students' => [
        'provider' => 'students',
        'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Lo que me he fijado es que si al guard por default lo cambio de web a students este funciona al revez, me deja ingresar con usuarios del modelo studens, mas no del modelo Users.